# php comparison function not working as expected

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to check whether the entered text is URL or string. My goal is i should get "URL Detected" if entered text is www.yout.com,http://stackoverflow.com, etc

```
if (stripos($text, ".com") !== false) {
    echo "URL Detected";
}
```

Comment: looks fine. What is your question?

Comment: [It works correctly](https://3v4l.org/MssSb)

Answer (score 0):

you mast use `filter_var`

```
$incomingData = "www.google.com";
$url = filter_var($incomingData, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
if ($url !== false) {
    echo "URL Detected";
}
```

Comment: If you'll read the docs you'll see that `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` passes some URL's which may not be considered valid.

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression to check if it's an url.
For example :

```
$regex = "/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/"
if(preg_match( $regex , "www.google.com" ){
    echo "URL Detected"
}
```

Comment: "Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'"; Also doesn't work with newer TLDs (like .museum)

Comment: Try "/^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?/i" as regex